# How to change the div element after ajax call?

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

### Only the first row of the table is changing

---

HTML table

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
    <td>{{ $entrepreneur->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $entrepreneur->contact }}</td>
    <td>{{ $entrepreneur->address }}</td>
    <td>{{ $entrepreneur->business_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $entrepreneur->business_address }}</td>
    <td>
        <div id="approval">
            <button class="check-btn" id="check-btn-{{ $entrepreneur->id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#checkModal-{{ $entrepreneur->id }}"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
            <button class="delete-btn" id="delete-btn-{{ $entrepreneur->id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rejectModal-{{ $entrepreneur->id }}"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

Ajax Function

```
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: "/changeAccepted/"+entrepreneur_id,
success: function(res) {
 toastr["success"]('Entrepreneur accepted succesfully');
 $('#checkModal-'+entrepreneur_id).modal('hide');
 $('#approval').html('Accepted');
} });
```

---

I am trying to change the two buttons on 'id=approval', right now it is changing for only the first row. I also want to change for other rows when it is accepted.

Comment: Didn't you ask this in another question earlier? Does all divs have the same id `approval`? Id's _must_ be unique within a document.

Comment: What other rows?  The HTML shown has only one row.  (And what looks like template code, unrelated to the resulting HTML that the JavaScript uses.)  Guessing from the description, it sounds like you're re-using the same `id` in your HTML, which is invalid.

Comment: It is best practice to have a unique id for each element in same document. Also, if you call the jquery using ID, it will only apply to the first occurrence but if you call jquery using class syntax, it will apply to all.  Though you need to implement the mechanism to restrict the script from changing the current row's HTML.

Comment: i changed the id=approval to approval-$entrepreneur->id and also make changes to ajax call, it works now..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each html element on same page has to have unique `id` property.

As you are using table I think you have multiple rows and each row has its own buttons placed in `<div id="approval"></div>` element.

When you use `$('#approval')` selector, Jquery gets only first one.

If you want to select all and change every element you have to use any selector but `id`.

The simplest way is to use `.class` selector.

Example & Solution:

**Html:**

```html
...
<div class="approval_class">
  <button class="check-btn" id="check-btn-{{ $entrepreneur->id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#checkModal-{{ $entrepreneur->id }}"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
  <button class="delete-btn" id="delete-btn-{{ $entrepreneur->id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rejectModal-{{ $entrepreneur->id }}"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
</div>
...
```

**Javascript (Jquery): (to change all rows as accepted)**

```
$('.approval_class').html('Accepted');
```

**Javascript (Jquery): (to change only that row which accepted)**

```
 $('#delete-btn-' + entrepreneur_id).closest('div').html('Accepted');
```

Comment: I don't think using a class would be ideal for the OP as I think they want to change specific buttons as each row is accepted, not to change all of them.